# Full Text Search Index in MySql?

Tags: mysql

i am writing a query using full text search index is it right or wrong.

```
SELECT sum(p_bi.iQty)
FROM patientbillitem p_bi, patientbillpayment p_b
WHERE Match(p_bi.vItemCode) Against( 'pbi.vItemCode')
```

pbi.vItemCode is separate table column is take it as a string is it true or not?

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL documentation on [match() ... against() ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) says:

> AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

This means that your query will search for the **string** literal of `'pbi.vItemCode'` within `p_bi.vItemCode` field, not for the contents of the `pbi.vItemCode` field.